# Salt values for REST API

Tags: java, spring-security

I am creating an REST based web application which, after successful user credentials validation, generates auth token and authenticates subsequent requests using this auth token.

The contents(although not fixed yet) of token are 
AES_encrypt{username:SHA_256(username,user_specific_salt):timestamp:expiry_period}.

To avoid db call, I am trying to generate salt value based on  username itself.
Also, I am not sending salt value to client.

The problem is, I am a bit confused about the solution since the articles I have read so far suggest not to generate salt values on the fly but store at db level. Can someone help me figure out the optimal solution for the above scenario?

Comment: Optimal depends on a number of things. What you have to do is analyse your use case. What you need to do is when you read these articles ask yourself what the author is assuming and what attacks they are trying to make more difficult.

Comment: For me optimal means minimum calls to DB.since passwords stored at backend using bcrypt hash,there is less chance of successful password stealing.I am more inclined towards minimum DB calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the use-case and level of the security concerns. Having safely stored passwords hashes is of course more important and sensitive than for example authorisations tokens for a web-service of limited functionality.

So the analysis is based on potential risks/benefits of particular solution.

Firstly, look what would happen if you were not using salting at all. Then if someone captures your token and knows its structure (username plus timestamp) may try to recover the key used for the encryption. It is a computational challenging task but in principle possible. Having access to only one or many tokens generated in the same way does not make this task much easier (I may be mistaken, they may be some loop holes in the AES encryption).

The aim is to get your key used for the encryption so that attacker may produce its own valid token for arbitrary user later on.

- hacker needs to crack the key

You add a salt, even a fixed one for all the users. 
Hacker still has to crack you encryption key, same as before. Once it has it

He takes old token, and updates the timestamp and the job is done. He just copies the original hash. as the timestamp was not hashed useing the salt, so it is not affected.

So lets assume you hash username+salt+timestamp. Otherwise salting is irrelevant as explained above.

So the hacerk needs to crack the salt so it can reproduce the correct hash. Having multiple hashses encoded with the same salt makes it easier to recover the salt. SHA is fast enough to allow brute false attacks nowadays.

- hacker needs to crack the key
- hacker needs to get one salt from all the hashes
  By salting you introduced one extra step for the hacker to deal with but not a difficult one.

You add on the fly generated salt, 
Hacker cracks the encryption. Then he needs to crack multiple hashes to recover few salts. He needs to guess the salt generation pattern to fake the token.

- hacker needs to crack the key
- hacker needs to recover multiple salts from the hashes
- hacker needs to deduce the salt generation pattern.

Knowing the pattern it can produce the tokens for any user. Without knowing the pattern it can produced tokens for the cracked users, it is probably enough for the hacker.

Randomly generated salt stored in the DB, one salt for user.

- hacker needs to crack the key
- hacker needs to recover salt from the hashe

Hacker cannot create tokens for any user, but once knowing the salt it can create token for the hacked user. The DB stored salt does not improved things much, just prevent arbitrary user access but it still allows 'cracked' user access.

Randomly generated salt stored in the DB and changed regularly (hourly, daily).
Now hacking the salt once, does not help in the future, as it will not match the new salt value. Cracking hashes takes longer than hour. So hourly update should be enough. But tricky to implement it correctly, so that the valid tokens would not expire upon salt update.

So depending when you  are on the scale of security paranoia and how important is your service you may step up the costs for the hacker.

I would say for your usecase, hashing with salt on the fly is completely fine just do add the timestamp to the messaged hashed, otherwise hashing has no effect.

Now, to prevent your secret key being discovered, you may considering salting our encryption key. That way if the encryption is cracked only for one user not all. But again if it is not banking applicaton, probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! A few web resources also mention that Generating (only) username based random salt is bad practice.So,what if I create a random salt using java's SecureRandom class's functionalty and send it in auth token?That way,Salt will not be based on username and does not need to be stored in DB.Since I will be using SSL for all requests,auth token encryption may not be needed either

Comment: Encryption is essential! Otherwise anyone can produce the valid token. The 'hacker' can have a valid ssl connection to your server. Sending salt together with hash inside your token is like not having the salt at all! For your use case, AES(user+timestamp) is enough, including the hash is just one extra obsticle as I explained in the answer

Comment: Well... in that case,I should store encrypted form of(username,salt) combination either in server cache memory or in DB(although this seems like bad from performance perspective)